# Grails exclusion not working at deeper level

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.0.3. In the `BuildConfig.groovy`, I have the below exclusion.

```
dependencies {
    runtime ('com.mycompany.apps.notification:client:1.2.1') {
        excludes([ group: 'xom', name: 'xom' ])
    }
}
```

My dependency tree looks like below.(created the tree using maven2)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] com.mycompany.apps.notification:notifytest:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.mycompany.apps.notification:client:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.mycompany.apps.notification:api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO]       \- com.mycompany.framework:platformservice.shared:jar:3.22.0:compile
[INFO]          \- com.mycompany.framework:saml.res:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]             \- xom:xom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]                +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO]                \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-8:compile
[INFO]                   \- (xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The exclusion is working fine till level 4 in the tree, but exclusion is disregarded below the level. In my example exclusion works till 'com.mycompany.framework:platformservice.shared' but not working at 'com.mycompany.framework:saml.res' and below.

I tried the same using maven 2.2 and the exclusion works in all the levels of the tree above. Am i missing some configuration in grails for exclusion to work at deeper levels ? Or is it a known issue ?

Comment: What does the grails dependencies look like?

Answer (score -1):

I have had similar problems like this... drives me bonkers.  There are several jira issues to fix dependencies issues in grails and hopefully they will get addressed in 2.3.  Anyway, to address your problem I generally exclude a higher dependency, then include it directly, then exclude the item I am actually trying to exclude from it.  Annoying, but it works.

so maybe something like this?

```
runtime ('com.mycompany.apps.notification:client:1.2.1') {
    excludes([ group: 'com.mycompany.framework', name: 'saml' ])
}


runtime ('com.mycompany.framework:saml.res:1.0.0') {
    excludes([ group: 'xom', name: 'xom' ])
}
```

Also sometimes dependency stuff in general gets screwy and I find grails --refresh-dependencies compile can do the trick.  Or, worse comes to worse delete the entire .grails directory.